# make work flow in jenkins for the multiple jobs

Tags: jenkins, hudson, dsl

[image]

I want to write the orchestration code to trigger the series of jobs. requirement
when job 1 successfully build the start job2 and job 3 parallelly ,when job 3 completed successfully then it starts job4 , and finally job 5 will trigger only when job 2 and job 4 complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Pipeline plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/) to model your desired workflow. Have a look at the section ["Creating a simple pipeline"](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/#creating-a-simple-pipeline) to get started. To execute Job2 and Job3 in parallel, use the `parallel` step as described in the guide.

Comment: I want to use build-pipeline-plugin to check the job status in visualization 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin

Comment: The plugin you provides as a link is a different Jenkins plugin than suggested. I'd recommend the Pipeline plugin (see my link above) as it is the officially supported functionality for modeling a pipeline provided by CloudBees. It's more flexible and also provides a visualization of your workflow.